# Meu terminal do vscode não exibe o resultado

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Boa tarde! Estou aprendendo Python em ambiente Windows e, em um exemplo o meu terminal não mostra o resultado desejado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu executo o código pelo terminal ele abre uma outra janela pedindo o raio (input).
Quando eu coloco qualquer número ele fecha e não informa o resultado.

Codigo:

```
#! python
from math import pi

raio = input('Informe o raio: ')

print('A area do ciruculo eh ', pi * float(raio) ** 2)
```

Comment: substitua a imagem pelo código para que possamos replicar seu exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira correta de executar o seu código seria invocar o python antes do script que deseja executar, desta forma teriamos:

```
python main.py
```

Estamos supondo que o nome do arquivo que deseja executar é `main.py`.

Saída:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\pessoal> python main.py
Informe o raio: 1
A area do ciruculo eh  3.141592653589793
PS C:\Users\pessoal>
```